# increasing custom variables in piwik

Tags: matomo

Have done the below mentioned setting for increasing custom variables in piwik---
const MAX_CUSTOM_VARIABLES = 15; in tracker.php in piwik

why I did this is because we don't have console functionality because as per the mentioned
on piwik's site the actual way should be  ---
const MAX_CUSTOM_VARIABLES = 15; in tracker.php in piwik

but when I performed the above step it gave me error **./console: No such file or directory**

moreover now the problem lies that even editing tracker.php is not working out for me.

Answer (score 1):

This const was removed in Piwik 2.*. There is no possibility to extend the number of custom variables in Piwik 1.*. Please update to the latest Piwik. Then you will be able to adjust the number of custom variables using this command:

```
./console customvariables:set-max-custom-variables 10
```

Please remember, that this command alters `log_visit`, `log_link_visit_action` and `log_conversion` tables, so it may take some time to complete.

Comment: Only the DB schema. Code is automatically detecting the maximum number of custom vars.